# product of sum of subarray?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

You are given a array $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots, a_n\}$. You have to find out the product of the sum of each subarray.
For example $\{1,2,3\}$, subarrays are $\{1\},\{1,2\},\{2\},\{2,3\},\{3\},\{1,2,3\}$ their sums are $1,3,2,5,3,6$ and product of these sums is $1\cdot3\cdot 2\cdot 5 \cdot 3\cdot 6 = 540$. (we can use big prime number to module the result) 
I know $O(n^2)$ algorithm to do this. Is there is a better way to do this?

Comment: I think no. Unless you try something recursive, say `f(begin_index,end_index,have_sum,started_subarray)=` `(a[begin_index]*f(begin_index+1,end_index,have_sum,False)` `if not started_subarray else` `(have_sum+a[begin_index]))` `*f(begin_index+1,end_index,have_sum+a[begin_index],True)`, but not exactly this function (this is $O(n^2)$ too).